# Using Libcurl to authenticate ntlm proxy without pass

Tags: windows, curl, proxy, libcurl, ntlm

i'm testing some network simple process to understand better and know how to work with NTLM.

Following this ([ntlm-proxy-without-password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276955/ntlm-proxy-without-password)) Q&A i found hot to uthenticate my transaction via ntml using the log information of the current user.

The command is this: curl.exe -U : --proxy-ntlm --proxy myproxy.com:8080 http://www.google.com

Know i have to do the same thing using libcurl since i need to achieve that result into the application i'm developing. There is a way to do this?

Following this Q&A i found hot to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved like a charm

```
curl_easy_setopt(ctx, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, ":");
```